# gettext return wrong language

Tags: php, gettext

I have the two file domain.po and domain.mo in the `/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/` folder. I'm using xampp on my local machine, with Windows 7.
When I set my default language `$lang='it'`, my pages are translated in english, and vice versa if `$lang== 'en'` it return italian language.

This is my code:

```
    if ($lang == 'it') {
        $str_language = 'it_IT';
    } 
    else if ($lang == 'en') {
        $str_language = 'en_GB';
    }

    $this->lang = $lang;

    putenv("LANG=$lang");

    putenv("LANGUAGE=$str_language");

    if (defined('LC_ALL')) {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, $str_language);
    }
    else {
        putenv( "LC_ALL={$str_language}");
    }

    // locale path
    $directory = realpath("../dev") . "/lib/lang";

    $domain = 'domain';

    if ( $lang != 'it') {

        $filename = "$directory/$str_language/LC_MESSAGES/$domain.mo";
        $mtime = filemtime($filename); // check its modification time

        // our new unique .MO file
        $filename_new = "$directory/$str_language/LC_MESSAGES/{$domain}_{$mtime}.mo";

        if (!file_exists($filename_new)) {  // check if we have created it before
            // if not, create it now, by copying the original
            copy($filename,$filename_new);
        }

        // compute the new domain name
        $domain_new = "{$domain}_{$mtime}";
    }
    else {
        $domain_new = $domain;
    }


    if (function_exists('bindtextdomain')) {

        bindtextdomain( $domain_new , $directory);

        bind_textdomain_codeset($domain_new, 'UTF-8');
        textdomain($domain_new);
    }`
```

How can I solve this issue?
Thanks

Edit: msgid are in italian, msgstr are in english
I hope the question is clear.

Comment: I have tried to cut `en_GB` folder for a while, restart apache and then moved in the 'locale' folder. The result is that I can't see any translation now, only text in italian